# error importing QtGui from Pyside

Tags: python, pyside

I just downloaded and installed PySide and I am getting this error when I try to import QtGui from PySide

```
$ python -c "from PySide import QtGui"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7QLayout11adoptLayoutEPS_
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed PySide from pip yesterday. 
Checked "python -c "from PySide import QtGui" everything importing fine.

Firs check if you have QtGui.so in "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/" directory, cause a have.

Some month ago trying to install PyQt from sources  got problem with compilation: everything looks fine, but some modules (including QtGui) was absent (can't remember but problem was in some config file).

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the: **__ZN7QLayout11adoptLayoutEPS_** from **/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so** file.

**You code is correct:** python -c "from PySide import QtGui"
**but the problem is on your os system**, download PySide from official website: https://pypi.python.org/packages/f1/32/63872fdc1d9e0de5aa0b05b9d1a17d868851c619cdc6998dd9d853556f1b/PySide-1.2.1.tar.gz#md5=b551d6ff68685013b59e478571f775bf

**If you are using Windows, run cmd and type this command:**

```
cd <type here the python path>
example: cd C:\Python27
```

and type:

```
python <here the path of the extracted and download pyside file>\setup.py install
example: python C:\users\someuser\pysyde_extractedfiles\setup.py install
```

**If you are usinc Mac OS X run the terminal and type:**

```
cd /<you_python_install_dir>
python /<your_extracted_pyside_files_path/setup.py install>
example: cd /opt/python27 && python /tmp/pyside_extracted/setup.py install
```

**If you are using Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, ArchLinux)**

```
wget <here_the_pyside_download_url>
cd /home/<you_username>/<you_extracted_pyside_folder>
python setup.py install
```

If you use python3 then type:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

**I hope this help you!**